# Strip off characters from output

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following structure generated by bs4, python.

```
['Y10765227', '9884877926, 9283183326', '', 'Dealer', 'Rgmuthu']
['L10038779', '9551154555', ',', ',']
['R10831945', '9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565', ',', ',']
['B10750123', '9952946340', '', 'Dealer', 'Bala']
['R10763559', '9841280752, 9884797013', '', 'Dealer', 'Senthil']
```

I wanna rip characters off and I should get something like the following

```
9884877926, 9283183326, Dealer, Rgmuthu
9551154555
9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565
9952946340 , Dealer, Bala
9841280752, 9884797013, Dealer, Senthil
```

I am using  `print re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])`

So basically I wanna remove the "[]" and "''" and "," and random ID which is in the start.

**Update**

```
onclick="try{appendPropertyPosition(this,'Y10765227','9884877926, 9283183326','','Dealer','Rgmuthu');jsb9onUnloadTracking();jsevt.stopBubble(event);}catch(e){};"
```

So I am scraping from this onclick attribute to get the above mentioned data.

Comment: is this whole thing a string or a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `str.join` and `str.translate` here:

```
>>> from string import punctuation, whitespace
>>> lis = [['Y10765227', '9884877926, 9283183326', '', 'Dealer', 'Rgmuthu'],
['L10038779', '9551154555', ',', ','],['R10831945', '9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565', ',', ','],
['B10750123', '9952946340', '', 'Dealer', 'Bala'],
['R10763559', '9841280752, 9884797013', '', 'Dealer', 'Senthil']]
for item in lis:
    print ", ".join(x for x in item[1:] 
                                 if x.translate(None, punctuation + whitespace))
...     
9884877926, 9283183326, Dealer, Rgmuthu
9551154555
9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565
9952946340, Dealer, Bala
9841280752, 9884797013, Dealer, Senthil
```

Comment: How do I add that to the following ? I am new to this.

       `properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
for eachproperty in properties:
 print "http:/"+ eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string, re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])`

Comment: @Venky Apply it to the part that is returning those lists.